# Can I use a SynchronizationContext to post or send work to a thread currently running a message pump?

Tags: c#, multithreading

If I have a thread for which I run:

```
Application.Run();
```

If I post or send work to that thread, will the work be run in that thread?

***Edit for a bit more information.**

The exact use case is as follows. If I pulled the SynchronizationContext off of a Forms UI thread. If I posted or sent work to that thread using the Post() or Send() methods of the SynchronizationContext object, would the UI thread execute that work or is there some other mechanism by which that work executes?

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean. A complete sample would really help.

Comment: Yes, unless the thread is busy doing something else. Also, ensure you call post/send from the thread's synchronization context

Answer (score -1):

Yes, It does work. The answer was pulled from:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I